completely in red instead of shattered style
i want to mark the area under my graph. I want to have it hatched, but it is completely red. does anybody know how to fix it? thanks!
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=\figurewidth,
        height=\figureheight,
        scale only axis,
        xmin=-20,
        xmax=20,
        xlabel={x in \si{\celsius}},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=100,
        ylabel={y in \si{\percent}},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
  anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ]



    
   \addplot[black, thick, domain=-20:15] {15*100/35 -100*x/35};
     \addplot[color=red,fill=red, pattern=north east lines,  domain=-20:15,samples=100] {15*100/35 -100*x/35} \closedcycle;
            \node at (15 , 10) {B};
              \node[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1.5pt] at (axis cs:15,0) {};


    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


UPDATE: i tried to fix it by implementing the first idea - unfortunately it didnt work
\addplot[pattern color=red, pattern=north east lines, domain=-20:15,samples=100] {15100/35 -100x/35} \closedcycle;

now it is just the line without any filling


Replace color=red,fill=red parameters with pattern color=red

@AndréC is right. More info here

Thanks for the response. I tried it but unfortunately it doesnt work:
know i wrote:    \addplot[pattern color=red, pattern=north east lines,  domain=-20:15,samples=100] {15100/35 -100x/35} \closedcycle;
now it is just the line without any filling

At home, this code compiles under Windows 11, with the MikTeX distribution and with the pdfLaTeX engine. Which compilation engine do you use? Which LaTeX distribution do you use? What operating system do you use?

@AndréC i use Overleaf in my chrome browser and im using a Windows11 Laptop.

I've just tested it on Overleaf and I've had no problems. Please provide fully compilable code, as your error obviously lies elsewhere.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-20, xmax=20,
ymin=0, ymax=100,
]
\addplot[thick, domain=-20:15, samples=2] {15*100/35-100*x/35};
\addplot[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=red, domain=-20:15, samples=2] {15*100/35-100*x/35} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


